# How do I broadcast a live event over a phone (land) line?

Tags: audio-recording, microphone

I'm running a live event where there's a panel discussion. The panelists will be mic'ed and there will be an audio setup with receiver and speakers.

I know it's old school but I want to broadcast what the panelists say over the phone. I have a phone connection in the room. Do I just get a handset, leave it on the ground, and let it pick up the audio. Seems like the quality will be pretty poor. Is there another economical option I can pursue?

Answer (score 1):

You could go with a VOIP (voice over Internet Protocol) solution. There are several services arround and Skype could be a good one for this.

The "simplest" way would be to setup all your mics, connected to a computer (via whatever hardware you would normally use), and if (for instance) using skype, setup the input to the external mics connected.

Then use skype to call the landline number. Note that you need to pay for the call, prices vary.

There are more technological correct methods, but this one IMO is very easy and straightforward.

Comment: How is Skype "not really VOIP"?

Comment: @Flimzy Skype is VOIP indeed, but in a peer to peer fashion (not like other VOIPs where you have client to server).

Answer (score 1):

You need an interface box. Something like this. 
http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/380766-REG/Rolls_PI9_PI9_Phone_Patch_II.html

You can run your audio out of your mixer into this. There are better models, but for a one time event you might want to go the cheap route.

Comment: That model seems to be an output device for recording calls.  Will it also work as an input device?

Comment: My bad. I have this exact model...http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/284518-REG/JK_Audio_INLINE_InLine_Patch_Telephone.html